# Prompt user for confirmation when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, html, confirmation

I have a link that does some potentially dangerous function (delete something). I want to prompt user if he really wants to do it. I want to do it with javascript and it should be very simple.

My solutions so far:

```
<a href='/delete' onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?")'>delete</a>
```

.. is bad in a way that it is not triggered by middle click in Firefox and IE.

```
<a href='/delete' onmousedown='return confirm("Are you sure?")'>delete</a>
```

.. does not work. Even if true is returned on clicking Ok, link is not navigated.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: Which browser are you having problems with? The first solution seems to work for left and middle clicks in Chrome.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a button instead of link

Comment: Don't use a link (or any kind of GET request) to delete stuff. The HTTP spec defines GET as being safe. Use a form with a submit button. (And then middle click won't bypass the onsubmit event).

Comment: Why as comments, not as answers?

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: +1 because even though I wouldn't use it for delete confirmation, it's useful for other things like telling the user the form data they're editing will be lost if they navigate away.

Answer (score 18):

```
<a href='#' onclick='confirmUser()'>delete</a>
```

**javascript**

```
 function confirmUser(){
    var ask=confirm("Are you sure");
    if(ask){
      window.location="/delete";
     }
}
```

Comment: Change window.loaction to window.location

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this problem for an online banking client.  FDIC requires a confirmation "speedbump" whenever the user is navigating to a third party site.  We wanted to do it unobtrusively, and make it impossible to get around.

I've tested this with IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Android-- click, right click, middle click, shift click, shift F10, enter, long tap, everything (Firefox is the hard one).  Either you get the speedbump or you get a blank tab, you can't get around it.

```
document.ready = function() {

    var handleSpeedBump = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
        var sure = confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate to " + href + "?  This is a third party site and not owned by this institution.");
        if (!sure) return;
        document.location = href;
    }

    $("a.speedbump")
        .click(handleSpeedBump)
        .bind("contextmenu", handleSpeedBump)
        .dblclick(handleSpeedBump)
        .each(function() {
            var href = this.href;
            this.setAttribute("data-href", href);
            this.href = "javascript:void('Navigate to " + href.replace("'", "") + "')";
        })
}
```

To make this work, just write your link per normal and add "speedbump" to its classes.

```
<A href="www.thirdpartysite.com" class="speedbump">Here is the link!</A>
```

Comment: The class on the anchor element should be "speedbump" (no dot before), but great work indeed.